# get most recent row

Tags: mysql, sql

tables :

**task** : *id*(bigint) *name* (varchar). holds task details

**job** : *id*(varchar(UUID)) *task_id*(bigint (id of class)),*staus*(varchar(50)),*created_time*(time stamp). hold task execution details

possible values for status are FAIL/COMPLETED/INTERRUPTED

what i am trying to achieve is to
get all the most recent  values for each and every task from the job table

if job is not present for a task then return status as null

```
SELECT
    p.id, j.status
FROM
    tas p
        inner JOIN
            job j ON j.task_id = p.id
        inner JOIN
    job j1 ON j.task_id = j1.task_id and j.create_time > j1.create_time;
```

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: mysql version is 5.7 @jarlh

Comment: Have a subqeury where you get each latest created_time. JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL versions that support `ROW_NUMBER()` you could do:

```
WITH info as(
  SELECT
    p.id, 
    j.status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY j.created_time DESC) AS rn
  FROM tas p
  LEFT JOIN job j ON j.task_id = p.id
)
SELECT id, status
FROM info
WHERE rn = 1
```

Otherwise, just use a cte or sub-query.

```
SELECT p.id, t.status
FROM tas AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT task_id, MAX(created_time) as created_time
  FROM job
  GROUP BY task_id
) as lt
ON p.id = lt.task_id
LEFT JOIN task AS t ON lt.task_id = t.task_id AND lt.created_time = t.created_time
```

Comment: In the comment `MySQL` version is 5.7 which doesn't support window function like ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: @ErgestBasha Good point. Provided an alternative solution.

Comment: Unfortunately `WITH` is only supported on `MySQL 8+` versions. You need a subquery